# merge several bits of data from different sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to merge several bits of data from different sheets. After a few questions and attempts (at arrays, thanks to Stackoverflow before for help with this), i think a dictionary may be best. The final outcome is a populated table that holds all data for each individual entry. (depending on the entry the data in a column in raw data could be in different locations)

The data can include multiple entries for one person. But the data for each entry is different depending on the stage of entry. For example, if the data in column 3 would be in column 5 of the final table if a condition was stage 1, however if condition was stage 2, the same data that was in column 3 could be column 10 of the final table.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8fSY_4p93s

Following this video tutorial ondictionaires, i think i could o through the dtaa and find each individual entry and then add the corresponding variables for the case. E.g. find data for Steve Smith, if steve smith exists then if stage 1, add data to variable stagedate1, if stage2 add data to stage2date and so on. If not found add entry and find the stage.

Similar to the video, where he finds the corresponding data for each customer, and adds sales and volumes, i could do the same if an if function is round before to identify which datastage and to then put the value in correct variable.

I know there will be a million way to do it, but this seems simple and effective.

```
Sub Dictionary()

Dim dict As Dictionary

Set dict = ReadData()

Call WriteDict(dict)

End Sub

Function ReadData()

Dim dict As New Dictionary

Dim DataWs As Worksheet: Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Dim PoolOfWeekWs As Worksheet: Set PoolOfWeekWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pool of the week")

Dim LastrowData As Long: LastrowData = DataWs.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LastColData As Long: LastColData = DataWs.Cells(1 & DataWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


Dim LastColDataString As String: LastColDataString = Split(Cells(1, LastColData).Address, "$")(1)

Dim DataRange As range: Set DataRange = DataWs.range("A1:" & LastColDataString & LastrowData)
Dim DataArr As Variant: DataArr = DataWs.range("A1:AO" & LastrowData)

Dim range As range: Set range = DataWs.range("A1").CurrentRegion

Dim i As Long
Dim CandidateProcessID As String, CandidateName As String, FirstName As String, ProcessStatus As String, PQLDate As Date, oCandidate As ClsCandidate

For i = 2 To range.Rows.Count
    CandidateProcessID = range.Cells(i, 10).Value
    CandidateName = range.Cells(i, 16).Value
    FirstName = range.Cells(i, 17).Value
    ProcessStatus = range.Cells(i, 9).Value
    
    If dict.Exists(CandidateProcessID) = True Then
        Set oCandidate = dict(CandidateProcessID)   'CODE ERRORS HERE AFTER A FEW ROWS (Comes across a 
    Else                                             an entry that is already in the dictionary)
        Set oCandidate = New ClsCandidate
        dict.Add CandidateProcessID, oCustomer
    End If
    
    oCandidate.CandidateName = oCandidate.CandidateName
    oCandidate.FirstName = oCandidate.FirstName
    oCandidate.ProcessStatus = oCandidate.ProcessStatus
    oCandidate.PQLDate = oCandidate.PQLDate
Next i

Set ReadData = dict


End Function

Sub WriteDict(dict As Dictionary)

    Dim key As Variant, oCandidate As ClsCandidate
    
    For Each key In dict
        Set oCandidate = dict(key)
        Debug.Print key, oCandidate.CandidateName, oCandidate.FirstName, oCandidate.ProcessStatus, oCandidate.PQLDate
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(1 & DataWs.Columns.Count)` would be BMF8, which is probably not what you want.  Try `Cells(1, DataWs.Columns.Count)`

Comment: "CODE ERRORS HERE"  - exactly *how* does it error?

Comment: I believe the error is object error. It stops and debugs. Thanks for spotting that, but I don’t think that’s causing the error as I’m using a different range. Out of what ive explained, is a dictionary with a class the best method?

Comment: Where is `oCandidate` declared, and what is `oCustomer` ? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I believe the error is object error. It stops and debugs.*

That would be "Object Required", and it's absolutely consistent with a very common trap: add `Option Explicit` at the top of *every module*, and now VBA won't let you run the code until it knows what `oCustomer` is.

`Option Explicit` being missing has allowed the code to run with `oCustomer` undeclared: simply, a new `Variant/Empty` pointer is created on-the-spot for that local identifier ("oCustomer"), such that every iteration that "works" is just preparing the ground to make the ones that don't, blow up:

```
    If dict.Exists(CandidateProcessID) = True Then
        Set oCandidate = dict(CandidateProcessID) '<~ Variant/Empty is retrieved here: "object required"
    Else
        Set oCandidate = New ClsCandidate
        dict.Add CandidateProcessID, oCustomer '<~ Variant/Empty is added here
    End If
```

The `Variant/Empty` is successfully retrieved from the dictionary: the problem is that the `Set oCandidate` instruction on the left side of that `=` operator says the right-hand side of the operation must be an object reference. `Variant/Empty` fails to satisfy this requirement, and an "object required" run-time error is raised.

The bug isn't with the retrieval: it's with the storage!

You can easily find bugs like this with *static code analysis* tooling, such as [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) (disclosure: that's my website).

Comment: Hi @MathieuGuidon thanks for that silly mistake not sure how i missed that! Question, do you think my idea of using a dictionary is a good idea? to collect data on a Candidate from several sheets and columns and the populate a master sheet.